# Messed up $PATH variable in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, osx-lion, path

I did something to my PATH.

I was trying to add some new path and now none of the command like `open ~/.bash_profile` work, and `echo $PATH` only shows one path which is `/Application/Filename`.

Is there a way to fix this? This is my Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 7):

If you messed up your `~/.bash_profile` you can always edit it by supplying the absolute path to the editor:

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Remove any changes to `PATH` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>↩</kbd>. Overwrite the file and reload your shell. Your path settings should be restored.

Other files that set your `PATH` on OS X are:

- `~/.bash_login` (if `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist)
- `~/.profile` (if `~/.bash_login` doesn't exist)
- `/etc/profile`
- Everything in `/etc/paths.d/`
- Finally, for GUI apps:  `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`

---

Always remember to use the correct formatting for your new `PATH`, depending on whether you want your custom binaries to take precedence over system binaries:

```
export PATH=/some/other/path:$PATH
```

… or the other way 'round:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path
```

Comment: Alternatively, open `.bash_profile` in any GUI text editor, e.g. TextEdit, by pressing `Cmd-Shift-.` in the *Open…* dialog to display hidden files and folders.

Comment: one fore question though, i do the export PATH.... on the terminal, and every time i reload the terminal the path is not set. how do i make it the permanent path ?

Comment: never mind i answered my own question. i used 
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile and wrote the path there, saved it and restarted the terminal, now everything is working fine.