# Mac Pro - $PATH messed up and "command not found" errors

Tags: macos, mac, bash, python

I was installing opencv Python on my Macbook pro el capitan and in setting up the path messed up my .bashrc or path etc.  I tried several of the suggestions on the SO and SU, to no luck, now i am scared of messing up even more, (sorry am a mac newbie)

```
Sans-MBP:~ San$ echo $PATH
//anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Could someone help me with restoring the `$PATH` variable back? Thanks in advance

Edit: I did open my .bashrc in nano and this is what it shows

```
# added by Anaconda 2.2.0 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Now i am not sure what it should be to restore it. That's where I need help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Messed up $PATH variable in Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/472906/messed-up-path-variable-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: This is reasonable to have in your path. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `export PATH=foo` line from your .bashrc/.bash_profile. Then you just quit and reopen the terminal.